# How to change the icon of jLabel in code in java?

Tags: java, icons, jlabel

im trying to change the icon of a jLabel named "mainDot". i have another folder in the source packages (named "Images") that contains the icons i want to put on the mainDot when I press it.

```
private void mainDotMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    mainDot.setIcon(DOT_SMALL.jpg);
}
```

How would I be able to change the icon of mainDot?

Comment: use `ImageIcon` for that. it should work

Comment: By writing some code? Search for action listener...

Comment: ImageIcon does not work, it just gets rid of image already on the jLabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Test() {
    JLabel t=new JLabel();
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    t.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Path to image goes here"));
    this.add(t);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);  
}
```

this one is working. and as suggested use an actionlistener to do it on button press

Comment: doesn't work. it just makes the image already in the jLable disapear, then nothing happens after that

Comment: and in which way is it not what you want? you never state that you want multiple icons in the label which is as i know not possible

Comment: sry my fault i guess i did not add all information, the ImageIcon method works now. i just had to add src cause pics were in a file under the src file. I wanted to replace the existing pic inside the jLabel.